# LessCSS coding standards

Tags: css, coding-style, standards, less

Are there any?

After switching to [less](http://lesscss.org/), I usually end up with code like this:

```
.topNav{    
  prop: value;
  ...

  li{    
    prop: value;
    ...

    &:hover{
      ...
    }

    &.active{
      prop: value;
      ...

      a{
        prop: value;
        ...

        &:hover{
          prop: value;
          ...

          span{
            ...
          }
        }

        span{
         ...
        }

      } 

    }

    a{
      prop: value;
      ...

      &:hover{
        prop: value;
        ...
      }    

    }  

  }

}
```

Is it bad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it's not ideal. You should check out http://smacss.com -- awesome book on CSS organisation. It's not LESS specific, bit still very relevant.

One of the principles has to do with the depth of selection. Part of your LESS above compiles to `.topNav li.active a:hover span` which is starting to get a little deep (at least 4, plus whatever elements exist in the hierarchy between the ones listed). The problem with this it tightly coupled your CSS to a specific HTML structure. Makes it harder to change your markup later without breaking CSS.

LESS offers a lot of cool tools, but, in my opinion, the ability to nest selectors is one that is easily abused.

Comment: +1 - agree on nesting abuse - best less feature are variables and mixins - specially for color templates.

Comment: +1 - I was going to link to this book until I saw your answer. It's got the best framework I've seen for thinking about how to structure CSS code. It really helped me to understand why I loved some parts of my CSS code, but other parts just didn't smell right.